# UIImagePickerController Use Photo / Retake buttons don't work

Tags: ios, swift

I use default UIImagePickerController for taking photos / choosing them from a library. At some point, I present other ViewController over UIImagePickerController for customization of chosen photo. If a user selects Cancel option, I want to get him back to image choosing screen - in a case of camera source to screen with Use Photo / Retake buttons. After dismissing ViewController with customization buttons don't work (they work before).

I would rather not use AVFoundation here.

Here is some related code:

```
let storyBuilder = StoryBuilderViewController.storyboardController()

storyBuilder.delegate = self

photoPickerController.present(storyBuilder, animated: true)
```

This way I'm presenting my customization screen.

```
func resetButtonTapped(_ storyBuilder: StoryBuilderViewController) {
    storyBuilder.dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

This code runs after dismissing.

So, nothing special, but buttons stop working

View Hierarchy looks like this:

[image: View Hierarchy]

So, there is nothing over this screen. Buttons properties isEnabled set to true. UIImagePickerController isn't nil. isUserInteractionEnabled is true

I've created a [simple project](https://github.com/Hatko/CameraTest) with this error. It doesn't work either. 
Also, I've just had a case, when camera stops work entirely, even after app restart, with logs full of errors. Only restart of my phone helps.

**More description**

I have a start screen - RootViewController. I need to present UIImagePickerController with a camera over it. After a user makes a photo I need to present another controller - EditViewController (not dismissing UIImagePickerController, so if a user wants to take another photo - he just goes back). I do it like this:

```
picker(editController, animated: true) //picker - UIImagePickerController, editController - edit controller
```

As I said before, my user can go back - and here is a problem - if I dismiss editController, buttons on UIImagePickerController don't work.

Please, ask some questions, I don't understand, why is it hard to get my issue correctly.

Comment: Have you tried using the live Debug View Hierarchy in Xcode? Whenever buttons stop working for me I suspect a view (invisible) that I've left lying around on top of the buttons.

Comment: @Magnas, check my updates

Comment: @VladHatko will you share project? I will try to solve it then return back to you.

Comment: added additional info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had Checked your demo code and make certain changes to make it work as you wants it.
1) Please check ViewController class code.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    fileprivate var photoPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    let notificationIdentifier: String = "StartCamera"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // Register to receive notification
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.cameraSetUp), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: notificationIdentifier), object: nil)
    }

    func cameraSetUp(){
        photoPickerController.sourceType = .camera
        photoPickerController.cameraDevice = .front
        photoPickerController.delegate = self
        present(photoPickerController, animated: true)

    }
    @IBAction func showCamera(_ sender: Any) {
        cameraSetUp()
    }
}

extension ViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    public func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        guard let storyboard = storyboard else {return}
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EditingViewController")
        picker.dismiss(animated: true)
        present(viewController, animated: true)
    }

    public func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}
```

2) EditingViewController class code

```
class EditingViewController: UIViewController {
    let notificationIdentifier: String = "StartCamera"

    @IBAction func dismissButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        // Post a notification
        dismiss(animated: true)
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: notificationIdentifier), object: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: customization view isn't a view, but just another viewController, which I remove on a cancel button tap. you can easily reproduce a problem from example project I've attached. there is nothing over UIImagePickerController

Comment: unfortunately no, it doesn't. you present imagePicker one another time

Comment: yes, i had dismissed when presenting another controller and on dismiss of 2nd controller again presented the camera. Coz picker will not work correctly if you keep it open.

Comment: I've noticed it :) that's why I'm asking if anybody knows the solution to keep it in correct state

Comment: you can play a little with it - it doesn't work only for camera; picker with library source works perfectly after presenting something over it

Comment: When you dismiss 2nd controller you will come back to controller one with current state having 2 buttons retake and Use Photo. If you can show fresh camera instead of showing current state then this problem can be resolved. And I think I had done the same. But If you could find something more accurate please keep it posted here. Thanks.

Comment: yes, you're totally right - just I had to do it the way with retake / use photo buttons

Answer (score 1):

So your problem is that you´re stacking your `controllers`. You don´t need to do that. Another thing is that your `cancel button` in your `viewController` has no usage. You do also need to hold a reference of the `UIImagePickerController` making it an instance property of your view controller and present it.

Code below:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    let photoPickerController = UIImagePickerController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        photoPickerController.delegate = self
    }


    @IBAction func cancelBtnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        showFrontCamera()
    }

    @IBAction func showCamera(_ sender: Any) {
        showFrontCamera()
    }

    func showFrontCamera() {
        photoPickerController.sourceType = .camera
        photoPickerController.cameraDevice = .front
        present(photoPickerController, animated: true)
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        print("didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo")
        if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
            // your image
        }

        picker.dismiss(animated: true){
            // any code after dismissing the controller
        }
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        print("imagePickerControllerDidCancel")
        picker.dismiss(animated: true){
            // any code after dismissing the controller
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't get your solution at first. what you're really suggesting is to do something like presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true). it doesn't help - after dismissing buttons don't work

Comment: @VladHatko yes, checkout my first comment I have included a link to your project with the updated code.

Comment: could you please check my question again? my task right now, to present editing screen, right after photo is taken, not dismissing UIImagePickerController. my example project just displaying an issue

Comment: what you've done - wrote simple UIImagePickerController flow. I can do that either. but my problem isn't related to your answer

Comment: @VladHatko, it´s really unclear what you want and your title is very misleading. Try to update your questions and title.

Comment: I've just pushed changes to my example project, so may be it become more descriptive

Comment: So if I understand your issue:
1: User presses Show camera
2: User takes camera
3: That image should be presented on a new view
4: On that view the user should be able to press "Show camera" or "Cancel"  and if the user presses cancel then the image shall be removed?

Comment: also, I changed my example project on github. it's hard to not understand the issue now

Comment: So the only thing you need help with is if the user takes an image and then presses cancel on the viewController you want to be able to retake the image/cancel in the pickerView?